# I'm having trouble dropping an Azure database from a partial restore

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I canceled a restore of an Azure database. That (partial?) database which resulted from that canceled restore now appears for all users who connect to the server via SSMS. The database does NOT appear in the Azure portal under the list of databases hosted on our Azure SQL Server instance.

I am logged in to the server with admin privilege. I am able to access all databases listed on this server; however, I am unable to access this particular database. I am unable to right-click and delete the database; an error dialog appears. Nor am I able to execute a drop database statement. Do you have any advice on how I can delete this malformed database artifact? Is there some artifact on the Azure portal which I need to delete in order to remove this database from appearing within SSMS? Thanks for your advice!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the crux of the problem when I issued the following query in the master database:

```
SELECT *
  FROM [sys].[databases]
```

[image]

As far as the database master is concerned, that database should exist on the server. But it doesn't, because the restore was cancelled and for whatever reason Azure did not do the proper housekeeping in the master database when the restore was cancelled. OK, says I. The master thinks that database exists so I'll create it!

In the Azure portal, I copied the 0900AM database to the target database *****_2022-02-11_0800AM. As soon as that database was created, all of a sudden interacting with the database via SSMS started working. I didn't even have to refresh the connection. I was then able to delete the database in the conventional manner.